# Replacement rules of xdebug name parameter %R

Tags: xdebug

What are the replacement rules applied on the URI that is used for the `%R` parameter in the output name configuration? The [documentation](https://xdebug.org/docs/all) (parameter:`xdebug.trace_output_name`) only gives an example, which could be interpreted in different ways :

`trace._test_xdebug_test_php_var=1_var2=2.xt`

could be either

`/test/xdebug_test.php?var=1&var2=2`

or

`/test_xdebug/test.php?var=1&var2=2`

or

`/test/xdebug/test.php?var=1&var2=2`

**(How) can I recreate the uri from a xdebug dump name?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the [xdebug source code](https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug/blob/master/usefulstuff.c) and found the function replacing the characters:

```
if (data) {
   strval = estrdup(Z_STRVAL_P(data));
   /* replace slashes, dots, question marks, plus
    * signs, ampersands, spaces and other evil chars
    * with underscores */
   while ((char_ptr = strpbrk(strval, "/\\.?&+:*\"<>| ")) != NULL) {
         char_ptr[0] = '_';
   }
   xdebug_str_add(&fname, strval, 0);                                                                                
   efree(strval);
}
```

**tl;dr:**`/\.?&+:*"<>|`

as a side node while experimenting with the character list using apache:

- the space is encoded as `%20` and thus not replaced by `_`
- <,> are encoded as `%3C` and `%3E` and thus not replaced by `_`
- `"` is encoded as `%22` and thus not replaced by `_`

Answer (score 0):

You can't go back from the generated file name to the full URL, as information is lost as some characters are basically replaced with `_` as you've added in your comment already.